# How to loop through pandas dataframe for same values and extract data from other columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

```
data = [['a', 10, '8/5/2021'], ['a', 15, '8/12/2021'], ['a', 8, '8/18/2021'], ['a', 5, '8/23/2021'], ['b', 3, '8/18/2021'], ['b', 10, '8/23/2021'], ['c', 8, '7/30/2021'], ['c', 12, '8/5/2021'], ['c', 3, '8/12/2021']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Hours Slept', 'Date'])
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new dataframe that shows the name, # of times the person slept 10 hours or more, and the dates that correspond to those times. Something like this:

[image]

The code should be able to account/ignore NaN and the symbol '*' in the hours slept column.

I know I can do something like this to figure out the # of times the person slept 10 hours or more:

```
counter = 0    
for i in df['Hours Slept']:
   if i >= 10:
       counter+=1
print(counter)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it in combination with the duplicate Names and how to extract the date.

I cannot select specific Names like using df.loc["a"] because I'll like something that can iterate through all the names (my code has more than a, b, c).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and use aggregation functions:

```
(
    df
    .query("`Hours Slept` >= 10")
    .groupby("Name", as_index=False)
    .agg({"Hours Slept": "size", "Date": ", ".join})
)
```

```
  Name  Hours Slept                 Date
0    a            2  8/5/2021, 8/12/2021
1    b            1            8/23/2021
2    c            1             8/5/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach:

```
df['over10h'] = np.where(df['Hours Slept'].ge(10), 1, 0)

df
    Name    Hours Slept Date        over10h
0   a       10          8/5/2021    1
1   a       15          8/12/2021   1
2   a       8           8/18/2021   0
3   a       5           8/23/2021   0
4   b       3           8/18/2021   0
5   b       10          8/23/2021   1
6   c       8           7/30/2021   0
7   c       12          8/5/2021    1
8   c       3           8/12/2021   0

df1 = df.loc[df['over10h'].ge(1)].groupby(['Name', 'over10h'])['Date'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Dates')

df1["# of times >=10"] = df1['Dates'].map(len)

df1 = df1.drop(columns='over10h')

df1
    Name    Dates                   # of times >=10
0   a       [8/5/2021, 8/12/2021]   2
1   b       [8/23/2021]             1
2   c       [8/5/2021]              1
```